# why tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0 is not avaiable to install for linux using conda

Tags: tensorflow, conda

A while ago I've installed `tensorflow-gpu` using : `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` which installed the version `2.3.0` on my Linux machine. Now I need to reinstall the library in a new conda environment and just found out the version is not available anymore in conda packages. Why is that and is there a way that I can install this specific version using conda again?
this is the result of conda list in my old environment which might be helpful:

```sh
# packages in environment at /home/marzi/anaconda3/envs/nc_gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu  
absl-py                   0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
aiohttp                   3.7.3            py36h27cfd23_1  
astor                     0.8.1                    py36_0  
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             3.0.1                    py36_0  
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blinker                   1.4                      py36_0  
blis                      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py36h27cfd23_1003  
bs4                       0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
c-ares                    1.17.1               h27cfd23_0  
ca-certificates           2020.12.8            h06a4308_0  
cachetools                4.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
catalogue                 1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2020.12.5        py36h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.14.4           py36h261ae71_0  
chardet                   3.0.4           py36h06a4308_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cryptography              2.9.2            py36h1ba5d50_0  
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0  
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0  
cupti                     10.1.168                      0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cymem                     2.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
cython                    0.29.21                  pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses               0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
emoji                     0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
flake8                    3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
gensim                    3.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.24.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0  
grpcio                    1.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0           py36hd6299e0_1  
hazm                      0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0  
idna                      2.10                       py_0  
idna_ssl                  1.1.0                    py36_0  
importlib-metadata        2.0.0                      py_1  
iniconfig                 1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254  
joblib                    0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libprotobuf               3.13.0.1             hd408876_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libwapiti                 0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.3.3            py36h06a4308_0  
matplotlib                3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mccabe                    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2020.2                      256  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py36he8ac12f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py36h23d657b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py36h0573a6f_0  
mock                      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 4.7.6            py36h7b6447c_1  
murmurhash                1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
nltk                      3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.18.5                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1i               h27cfd23_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 20.8                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pbr                       5.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.3.3           py36h06a4308_0  
plac                      1.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
preshed                   3.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.13.0.1         py36he6710b0_1  
py                        1.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0  
pycodestyle               2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pydot                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyflakes                  1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyjwt                     2.0.0            py36h06a4308_0  
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py36h06a4308_0  
pytest                    6.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest-timeout            1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.12               hcff3b4d_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2020.4                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
regex                     2020.11.13               pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0  
rsa                       4.6                        py_0  
sacremoses                0.0.43                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.23.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sentencepiece             0.1.94                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                51.0.0           py36h06a4308_2  
six                       1.15.0           py36h06a4308_0  
sklearn                   0.0                      pypi_0    pypi
smart-open                4.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 2.2                      pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0  
srsly                     1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0  
tensorflow                2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-addons         0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1  
thinc                     7.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
tokenizers                0.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
toml                      0.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.54.1                   pypi_0    pypi
transformers              4.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
typeguard                 2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                       0  
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0  
urllib3                   1.26.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wasabi                    0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wrapt                     1.12.1           py36h7b6447c_1  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yarl                      1.5.1            py36h7b6447c_0  
zipp                      3.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

Comment: Do you still have the old environment? If so, can you share the list of packages in that env?

Comment: @AMC I've edited the question and added your answer

Comment: Using Pip in a Conda environment is sort of a "*do at your own risk*" ordeal. There are [rules to that game](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env), but once you've broken them, the simplest solution is make a new environment (and often delete any packages you installed with `pip install --user`).

Comment: Based on the list of packages you shared, you had previously installed tensorflow-gpu through pip, not Conda.

Comment: Latest `conda install tensorflow-gpu` on Linux has Tensorflow 2.4.1 version. Take a look at [anaconda link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu). To install install specific version of Tensorflow use `pip`.  `pip install tensorflow==2.3` installs both GPU and CPU version. Thanks!